# Bypass stormpath when in development

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath

I am trying Stormpath via [`express-stormpath`](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath). I have very poor network connection so every time when the node app restarts, the page takes long time to response. It seems that the `express-stormpath` is doing something at background. The problem happens no matter which page I am accessing. It just takes few seconds to response even there is no stormpath validation on the route.

Can anyone tell me how to bypass all routines of Stormpath when in development mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply not include the Stormpath middleware in development.

For example:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(stormpath.init(app, ...));
}
```

This will **only** load the Stormpath middleware if your application has an environment variable named `NODE_ENV` set to `production`.

Comment: I noticed that it will cause errors in the registration/login page. May it's better to provide other way of disabling talking to the server. @rdegges